# Issues in JSON to XML and Upload to FTP in Ballerina Integrator

Tags: ftp, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, ballerina, integrator

I am trying samples given in Ballerina integrator tutorials, while running json to xml and then upload into ftp sample facing the issue:

```
error org.wso2.ei.b7a.ftp.core.util.BallerinaFTPException.
```

I knew the reason for this issue but don't know where i have to put that command. Please help me to sort out the issue.

Reason for the issue is: ftp credentials are mentioned in conf file, I put conf file under the root directory but it doesn't refer. Need to give

```
b7a.config.file=src/upload_to_ftp/resources/ballerina.conf
```

But I don't know where I have to give this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have passed credentials directly to ftpConfig then its working fine. Conversion happened and converted file has been uploaded into ftp location successfully

`ftp:ClientEndpointConfig ftpConfig = {
    protocol: ftp:SFTP,
    host: "corpsftp.dfaDFDA.com",
    port: 22,
    secureSocket: {
        basicAuth: {
            username: "DDFDS",
            password: "FADFHYFGJ"
        }
    }
};`

Output
    {
    "Message": "Employee records uploaded successfully."
    }

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add -b7a.config.file when running the generated jar file.

Official documentation : 
https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/ballerina-integrator/develop/running-on-jvm/

However, keeping the ballerina.conf file in the root directory should work. Ballerina looks for the conf file automatically when running. Make sure the conf file is outside the src directory.

---

For the error that you have mentioned, could you add in logs to see if the json has been converted to xml properly? Since the code is structured in a way that checks if the conversion has occurred, it should print an xml

```
if (employee is xml) {
            var ftpResult = ftp->put(remoteLocation, employee);
            if (ftpResult is error) {
                log:printError("Error", ftpResult);
                response.setJsonPayload({Message: "Error occurred uploading file to FTP.", Resason: ftpResult.reason()});
            } else {
                response.setJsonPayload({Message: "Employee records uploaded successfully."});
            }
        } else {
            response.setJsonPayload({Message: "Error occurred tranforming json to xml.", Resason: employee.reason()});
        }
```

The `if( employee is xml )` part will check if the conversion is successful.

The same applies after the file is sent to the server. If the file hasnt been sent, then the `ftpResult` would be an error. Basically, if you got the message `{ Message : "Employee records uploaded successfully" }` then all the checks should have passed.

Comment: Thanks. I directly passed ftp credentials now getting success message but json payload not converted into xml and also not loaded into my ftp path. Getting  "Message": "Employee records uploaded successfully." message alone.

Comment: Do you think you could log the 'employee' xml type to confirm that the conversion doesnt work?

Comment: conversion doesn't happened and not uploaded into my ftp location.

Comment: Can you add a log to print `employee` and attach the result?